# how to insert data through datagridview after selecting operation in combobox

Tags: c#

i have a combobox column in my datagridview in which i have added three items insert,update and delete now i wannt to choose one item and perform corresponding operation.

but when i do this error show input string is not in correct format,may be i am unable to select the exact row relative to that combobox row.will anybody help.

here is code of my combobox SelectedIndexChanged event of datagridview

```
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

if (cmb.SelectedItem.ToString() == "insert")
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=krishna-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbnew;Integrated Security=True");

    int a = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].ToString());
    string b = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string c = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    com = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable values(@a,@b,@c,@d)", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", "govind");
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been inserted");
 }
```

Comment: have you debug and check the values of a, b and c?

Comment: Which input string? Did you debug to find out if the row index is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just fix the line for Cell 1, You forgot the .Value property:

```
int a = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Value" Use "Text" .Like..

```
int a = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
string b = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
string c = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
```